# Why does my code repeat itself more than once in a file

Tags: python

Hello i am getting trouble with this code. When it writes to a file the text within the file repeats itself. When the code loops and more text is added it join on the text that was inserted. I was wondering if you could help me stop the text repeating itself but still write to a new line.
I want the 1st persons information to be on a 1 line and the second persons information to be on the second line and so on,Thanks you.

```
myFile1 = open("a-l.txt", "wt")

myFile2 = open("m-z.txt", "wt")


myList1 = ([])
myList2 = ([])

while 1: 
    surName = input("Enter your surname name:")
    if surName[0] in ("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L"):
        myList1.append(surName)
        title = input("Enter your prefered title:")
        myList1.append(title)
        firstName = input("Enter your first name:")
        myList1.append(firstName)
        bDay = input("Enter birthdate in mm/dd/yyyy format:")
        myList1.append(bDay)
        phoneNum = input("Enter your phone number:")
        myList1.append(phoneNum)
        email = input("Please enter your email.")
        myList1.append(email)
        for item in myList1:
             myFile1.write(','.join(str(x) for x in myList1) + '\n')

    elif surName[0] in ("M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"):
        myList2.append(surName)
        title = input("Enter your prefered title:")
        myList2.append(title)
        firstName = input("Enter your first name:")
        myList2.append(firstName)
        bDay = input("Enter birthdate in mm/dd/yyyy format:")
        myList2.append(bDay)
        phoneNum = input("Enter your phone number:")
        myList2.append(phoneNum)
        email = input("Please enter your email:")
        myList2.append(email)
        for item in myList2:
             myFile2.write(','.join(str(x) for x in myList2) + '\n')
    elif surName == "1":
        break
myFile1.close()
myFile2.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're actually using two for loops.  You're using a list comprehension to join the whole list into a single line and write it to the file, but you're doing that X times, where X is the number of items in the list.

```
for item in myList1:
     myFile1.write(','.join(str(x) for x in myList1) + '\n')
```

You don't need the outer `for` loop

```
myFile1.write(','.join(str(x) for x in myList1) + '\n')
```

Comment: It doesn't repeat the code again which is what i wanted but it joins the text in the file together. @Brendan Abel

Comment: What is the desired behavior? You don't want the text joined together?

Comment: Yes please,that would be helpful.

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of what you would like the output to look like

Comment: I don't see any example output.